# How can I pass a variable to a page with a SEF url?

Tags: plugins, urls

I'm making a website for a small church.  They would like to upload sermons to their site.  I've looked for a WP plugin to do that, but none of them did exactly what they wanted.  So, I'm making a plugin to do what they want.

I've made a page called 'sermons' that has a page template 'sermon archive'.  That file will display the sermon archive.  I'd like to have it so when  they click on a sermon, it would go to `sermon/my-sermon-name` (rather than `sermon?name=my-sermon-name`).  Is there a way to do that in  WordPress?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you storing sermons? As a CPT probably?

Comment: @Mridul Aggarwal I'm uploading them, and then storing the url, name, speaker, date, etc in a database (not created by WP).

Answer (score 1):

You have to either work it out with the [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) class or add this to the .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sermon/(.*)/ /sermon?name=$1 [L]
```

### UPDATE

Forgot to mention that the htaccess code is supposed to be above the wordpress generated htaccess code

Comment: I added that above the .htaccess (I changed `?name=` to `?sermon_name=`).  In sermon.php (the page template), I set it to `echo $_GET['sermon_name']`.  When I go to `/wordpress/sermon/my-sermon`, I get a 404 error.  When I go to `/wordpress/sermons/?sermon_name=my-sermon`, it shows my-sermon.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I put this code into a plugin: `add_rewrite_rule('^sermon/([^/]*)/?','sermons/?sermon_name=$matches[1]','top');`.  When I go to `/wordpress/sermon/my-sermon`, I get this error: 
**Fatal error**: Call to a member function add_rule() on a non-object in localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/rewrite.php on line 21

Comment: maybe this help http://www.prodeveloper.org/create-your-own-rewrite-rules-in-wordpress.html Don't forget to refresh your permalinks from admin panel

Comment: This code (`add_rewrite_rule('^sermon/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=sermons&sermon_name=$matches[1]','top');`) goes to the `sermons` page, but it doesn't pass the `sermon_name` argument.  How can I get it to do that?

Comment: try [add_rewrite_tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag)

Comment: If I echo `$wp_rewrite->rewrite_rules();` (for this rule), I get `index.php?pagename=sermons&sermon_name=`.  It looks like `sermon_name` isn't even getting passed.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with `$matches[1]` (in `add_rewrite_rule('^sermon/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=sermons&sermon_name='.$matches[1],'top');`).  How is that defined?

Comment: maybe `'index.php?pagename=sermons&sermon_name=$matches[1]'` ($matches[1] inside the string)

Comment: I found the answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7577/add-rewrite-rule-and-custom-variable/7582#7582

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer from [this page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7577/add-rewrite-rule-and-custom-variable/7582#7582).

The final code:

```
add_action('init','yoursite_init');
function yoursite_init() {
    global $wp,$wp_rewrite;
    $wp->add_query_var('sermon_name');
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('sermon/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=sermons&sermon_name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: And, as autor sad in [that page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7577/add-rewrite-rule-and-custom-variable/7582#7582)
you should add $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false); in yoursite_init() and remove it, after 1 execution to clear the sef-rules.